# #value error in sum array with substitutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula I currently have works fine as long as the cells contain a value. The issue I'm running into is I get a #value! error if I just have the letter in the cell. What I'm trying to accomplish is just get the sum of the cells. The image I posted is just a sample cell.

```
{=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3:B21,"c",""),"s","")))+0}
```

[Sample Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LycKv.jpg)

Comment: TRIM after you substitute and then concatenate a 0 to the front of the number before taking its value

Answer (score 0):

```
=sum(--(0&TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$3:$B$21),"c",""),"s","")))
```

-- is another way of taking the value.

Another possibility is to wrap your formula in an IFERROR function to return a given value when an error occurs.  See below with your formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3:B21,"c",""),"s","")))+0,"CUSTOM MESSAGE")
```

Remember to use your CSE for either formula.